# How to update plot data and color map in Octave?

Tags: matlab, plot, octave, colormap

I have a `surf` figure plotting a two dimensional function. I have a loop which changes the `z` values at each point `[x,y]` in a `meshgrid` matrix, in order to animate my plot:

```
p = surf(x, y, z)
frames = 10/1000

for t = 0:frames:10
    newZ = updateZVal(someArgs)
    set(p, 'ZData', newZ)
```

This works fine for the most part. However, the color map does not update. Basically the colormap texture of the original `z` matrix just stays there. The `x`-`y` plane moves up and down with changes in `newZ`, but the color does not.

This exact code works in Matlab, and it works fine in Octave except for this color issue.

**Edit**: Minimal working example. Little moving gaussian type thing. You can see the color does not update

```
figure();

x_range = [-2:0.2:2];
y_range = [-2:0.2:2];
[x,y] = meshgrid(x_range, y_range);
frames = 500;
z = (x) .* y;

p = surf(x, y, z);

for t = [0:2/frames:2]
    z = exp(-((((x-t).^2)/2) + (((y-t).^2)/2)));
    set(p, 'ZData', z);
    drawnow;
end
```

Comment: That sounds like an interesting problem. If you'd like to provide a minimal working example I'd be happy to have a look.

Comment: if I had to guess though, I'd say the colour data resides on the CData array. Have a look at the CData / CDataMode / CDataMapping / CDataSource properties

Comment: How is this possible `for t = 0:1000:10`?

Comment: @NKN because that expression results in a vector `t` ranging from `0` to `10` with `1000` steps

Comment: @NKN woops you're right, I was thinking about it wrong and haven't touched this language in a few months. My problem still stands though, I just typed that wrong in the example here

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou See my edit

Comment: omg you created a mexican wave! that's awesome! make the loop start from `-2` and it goes from edge to edge! \o/

Comment: @jphollowed just out of couriosity: do you want to create a gif or a video from at the end?

Comment: @jphollowed and does `t = 0:1000:10` really give anything else than 0 in Matlab?

Comment: @Andy No, like I said, It was a mistake. And yea maybe a gif

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr**: change

```
set(p, 'ZData', z);
```

to

```
set(p, 'ZData', z, 'CData', z);
```

---

**Explanation**:

Thank you for the minimal working example!

The reason colours don't seem to get auto-updated in octave, is because in matlab the surf object seems to provide an extra property called `cdatamode`, where `cdata` is the colour data, and the default value for `cdatamode` is `auto`, i.e. automatically update the colour information from the `zdata` if this changes.

Unfortunately octave does not provide this property, so if you set `zdata` manually to something else, you also need to manually update the colour information yourself. But, since this is just based on `z` anyway, all you have to do is update `CData` with the same values as `ZData`.

Clearly if you plotted the object from scratch each time you wouldn't have this problem, but doing it your way is preferable because it's much faster and smoother to animate (a **lot** faster in octave in fact for some reason!), and you don't get redrawing side-effects from having to plot axes again etc, so this is a good question! Many thanks!

Comment: The octave team generally treats such deviations from matlab as bugs, since they aim for the language to be fully compatible, so I would encourage you to [file a bug](http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?group=octave) :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that changing `Z` data does not change the color in the surf plot. Instead you should use a matrix `C`, assumed to be the same size as `Z`, to color the surface. See [Coloring Mesh and Surface Plots](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/visualize/coloring-mesh-and-surface-plots.html) for information on defining C.

Check this example:

```
[X,Y,Z] = peaks(25);
figure;
p = surf(X,Y,Z,gradient(Z));
for t = 0:1:10
    newZ = Z*rand(size(Z));
    p = surf(X,Y,newZ,gradient(newZ));
    pause(0.5);
end
```